# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException Error while invoking WebServices

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, wsdl, saxparseexception

I am new to web-services and digital certificate as well as signature. I am using Eclipse and Tomcat server to test my using soapUI.
I have given a WSDL and have generated the java classes and jars from given WSDL.

Now I am getting error while invoking the Web-services in which I am passing signature and certificate encoding as parameter to web-services.

`Error Message 4; nested exception is: 
    org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The markup in the document preceding the root element must be well-formed.`

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve it?

I am getting the following raw response.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Date: Mon, 13 Aug 2012 04:20:00 GMT
Server: Oracle-Application-Server-10g/10.1.3.1.0 Oracle-HTTP-Server
Last-Modified: Wed, 12 Nov 2008 14:09:58 GMT
ETag: "15d5db-f02-491ae3b6"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 3842
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you get this exception at? In Eclipse or SoapUI? The message just means the XML going in our out is missing end tags somewhere. Try writing your service without input parameters just to take those out of the mix of causing the error.

Did you write the web service, or are you just consuming the service? In SoapUI there is a tab on the screen next to the input side, one says Raw. If you click that, it will show you the data in xml form, and the same can be done on the right side for output. That may help you track down the missing end tag too.

---

Try running your code through, but comment out the actual call to the web service part, just to see if the issue happens prior to that.

Comment: Hi... 

 Thanks for ur reply.. i am getting this exception in eclipse . I am not writing the webservices.
Just we are consuming it.Its a third party wsdl . I am just sending the four IN parameters which is of 
signature and certificate chain which is base 64 encoded. And it does not contain any parameter for sending XML.

similarly i tried in SOAPUI . It shows the following raw response.Please give me some suggestion

Comment: What does your raw xml in soap look like?

Comment: My raw soap is just plain html page with 500 Internal Error which i mentioned in above . My reponse xml also displaying the plain html page with content of  <p align="left">
        An error occured whilst preparing this page for display.
      </p><p align="left">
        Due to technical issue, we are unable to process your request. Please
        try after some time. You can also send in your queries at 
         mentioning the process where you faced this problem. 
      </p>
      </p><p>

Comment: You need to find a way to figure out of the error is on the input you build or the output coming back. Bring up the wsdl in a browser and make sure it matches the data you are expecting back. Also comment out the web service command and see if your service still fails when you do not actually call the service command. Do everything but the method call.